# Galois group of an extension generated by character of a group

Tags: representation-theory, galois-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Let $G$ be a finite group with cardinality $m$ and let $IrrG=\{\chi_1,...,\chi_r\}$ be the set of all irreducible characters of $G$ in $\mathbb{C}$. Since $G$ is finite, then $\chi_i(g)=\sum \zeta_j$ with  $\zeta_j$ $m$-th root of unity.

If we denote $G$ as
$$G=\{g_1,...,g_m\},$$
we can consider the extension of $\mathbb{Q}$
\begin{align*}
    &K_i=\mathbb{Q}\big(\chi_i(g_1),...,\chi_i(g_m)\big) \\
    &K=\mathbb{Q}\big(\chi_1(g_1),...,\chi_1(g_m),\chi_2(g_1),...,\chi_r(g_m)\big)
\end{align*}
They are subfields of $Split_{\mathbb{Q}}(x^{m}-1)$. So $K_i/\mathbb{Q}$ and $K/\mathbb{Q}$ are Galois extension.

Now we have
\begin{align*}
    &\mathcal{G}_i=\mathcal{G}al(K_i/\mathbb{Q})\\
    &\mathcal{G}=\mathcal{G}al(K/\mathbb{Q})
\end{align*}
the Galois groups of this extension.

Are there some results which state a connection between $G$ and $\mathcal{G}$?

Comment: What do you want to know about the Galois group specifically? There is some discussion about the field $K$ in Serre's book.

Comment: In general these Galois groups are subgroups of $(\mathbb{Z}/\phi(m)\mathbb{Z},\cdot)^X$. But my idea is to connect this Galois group with $G$. Do you mean “local fields” of serre?

Comment: Right, but what do you mean by "connect with $G$"? Try to compute it for arbitrary $G$? What kind of relationship are you hoping for?

Comment: I'm not searching a specific result, but only properties that connect these groups. I don't know if they exist and if they are important result with connection in number theory. For example I'm searching properties of $G$ that induce property on $\mathcal{G}$ or on $K_i$ and vice versa. On Serre book I found "Artin representation", were you referring to this topic?